# Tkinter selected text color de-smoothing

Tags: python, colors, tkinter

I am designing a Tkinter GUI. In this screenshot characters "ials" are **selected**. Why is the color not smooth? Which color should I use?

[image: Non-smooth colors]

(Code):

```
entry1 = Entry(self,takefocus='off',justify='left',relief='flat',font=("Droid Sans",14),fg='#00ff00',bg='#000000',selectbackground='#000000',selectforeground='#005800',textvariable=entrystr,insertbackground='green',insertwidth=1,highlightbackground='#000000')
```

Comment: I don't see what you mean by "smooth".  Do you have the feeling that the selected characters are rendered differently?  Not antialiased or something?

Comment: Have you tried using one of the more common font, such as helvetica? Perhaps the font you've chosen is the culprit. I suggest a little more investigation.

Comment: @Alfe Yes, The characters on right on cursor are "pixely", at least that's how it looks on my LCD.

Comment: Hm, that screen shot you posted does not look more pixely on the right to me.  Maybe you try to solve a problem which does not exist ;-)